# Error while trying to run Junit test with Hibernate 5.2.1

Tags: java, hibernate

Trying to run a Junit test with Hibernate 5.2.1 and the following error has occurred:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet(Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor;)V is abstract
  at org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet(PersistentDateTime.java)
  at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:160)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2646)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2621)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2832)
  at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:41)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2840)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3411)

    .....
```

In our pom we have the next dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.spi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible jars (hibernate 5 and jadira.usertype

Comment: We also believe it`s a problem of incompatibility of versions, we tested with the latest versions of jadira.usertype but still doesn´t  work it.

Answer (score 3):

That project doesn't support the most recent Hibernate and relied on deprecated methods which were removed in Hibernate 5.2.

Instead you need to use the usertype.core version [6.0.0 or later](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a6.0.1.GA) as that was when support for Hibernate 5.2 was introduced.

The classes in the usertype.jodatime Maven artifact have been moved to usertype.core, so you'll need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
  <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```